# Acessar aplicação em uma máquina virtual com servidor Tomcat

Tags: windows, tomcat, virtualbox

não tenho certeza se posso perguntar aqui mas vamos lá, tenho uma demanda pois quero testar nessa máquina virtual o sistema em diferentes navegadores.

Problema que não consigo acessar, alguém já fez esse tipo de configuração?

Instalei na VM o `Windows Xp` com `Internet Explorer 6`. Mas pretendo fazendo `snapshots` de outros navegadores para testar.

Estou utilizando o `virtual box`.

Na máquina físico utilizo `Windows 8.1` e já fiz liberação da porta 8080 no firewall do Windows.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Eu tenho o ip da máquina real e virtual e consigo pingar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta é uma ótima forma de realizar testes de compatibilidade. Já fiz isso mutias vezes.

No caso, o problema pode estar em dois pontos:

### Configuração da placa de rede no VirtualBox

Aconselho a deixar em modo *bridge*, isto é, há uma simulação como se houvesse duas placas de rede e a máquina virtual participa da rede como uma máquina comum, tornando a configuração de acesso trivial.

### Configuração geral de rede

Liberar a porta no firewall pode não ser suficiente. Para tirar a prova, faça um rápido teste desabilitando o firewall completamente por alguns instantes.

Além disso, verifique se sua rede possui algum proxy ou firewall que pode estar bloqueando a porta.

Se há um servidor de domínio, verifique também se a máquina virtual está configurada adequadamente.

Também é bom ver se o IP da máquina virtual está conflitando com algum outro IP de outro usuário da rede. O ping pode ser um falso positivo.

Teste ainda se o sistema está acessível através de outro computador físico na rede.

Enfim, podem haver inúmeros problemas. Se nada disso funcionar, sugiro que descreve melhor o cenário na sua pergunta, incluindo os procedimentos realizados e o resultado de cada um um em detalhes (código, mensagem e print do erro).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, deixei em modo `bridge` e após isso desabilitei o `firewall` e nada, como devo acessar pelo navegador? Tem que configurar algo no `Tomcat` também?

Comment: @Macario1983 Em tese não é preciso configurar nada no Tomcat. Em geral isso é problema de rede mesmo.

Comment: Consegui! Problema era no endereço digitado! Exemplo de como deve ser. `http://seuip:8080/site`

Comment: @Macario1983 Detalhes, detalhes. Isso sempre acontece. Apenas note que esse `site` na verdade é o contexto da aplicação (*Application Context*), que deve ser usado mesmo quando acessado localmente.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda cara, eu não explicitei para deixar menos especifico, mas foi o que vi no `GUJ`.